# Issue with interface java/spring

Tags: java, spring, interface

I wrote this code

```
@Controller
public class StudentsController {

private ArrayList<student> students = new ArrayList<>();

private IStudentsRepository studentsRepository;

@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("students", students);
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/create")
public   String   create(@ModelAttribute student student)   {

    studentsRepository.create(student);

    return   "create";
}
.....
}
```

for a web application and I get this error java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.demo.Controller.StudentsController.create(StudentsController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
When I try to access the page create with its functionalities it doesn't work just gives me that error what is the problem? Also when I initialize the IStudent Repository interface IntelliJ tells me that studentsRepository is not assigned even if I used it to create method.

Comment: You should *inject* / *autowire* the `studentsRepository`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not injecting IStudentsRepository. Use `@Autowired`

You can use Field Injection like this

```
@Autowired
private IStudentsRepository studentsRepository;
```

Or the best way would be to use Constructor Injection.

```
@Controller
public class StudentsController {

private ArrayList<student> students = new ArrayList<>();

private final IStudentsRepository studentsRepository;

@Autowired
public StudentsController(final IStudentsRepository studentsRepository) {
   this.studentsRepository = studentsRepository;
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but it tells me "Couldn't autowire. No beans of 'IStudentRepository' type found.

Comment: how is your StudentsRepository class

Comment: I don't have StudentRepository class I only have the interface this one 
public interface IStudentsRepository {

    ArrayList<student> readAll();
    student read(int id);
    void create(student student);
    void update(student student);
    void delete(int id);
} and this class which implements the interface

Comment: then how can it work. you need to create a class implemeting IStudentsRepository inteface

Comment: public class StudentArrayListRepository implements IStudentsRepository {

    private ArrayList<student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    Override
    public ArrayList<student> readAll() {
        return students;
    }

    Override
    public student read(int id) {
        student stud = students.get(id-1);
        return stud;
    }

    Override
    public void create(student student) {
        students.add(student);
        student.setStudentId(students.size());
    }

  }

Comment: I have the class that implements the interface I posted up

Comment: and also in that class intellij tells me that the class is neve used

Comment: you need to put `@Component` on StudentArrayListRepository class